Libclang name of object from function call
Does anyone know how to get the name of the target object of a function call using libclang? I can find all cursors matching a function being called as you would expect by matching type to CALL_EXPR and matching either displayname or spelling but I really need to get the name of the target of the function being invoked. For instance if fun() is a member of class MyClass and I have the following code:
MyClass a;
a.fun();

How do I get "a". Im trying to start from the cursor with type is CALL_EXPR and spelling equals "fun" but that might not be the right approach.
Thanks
